# Python package or design that are helpful loading data to multiple cloud databases

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dictionary of data-frames each represent a table in a databases. I want to load all of these tables to multiple cloud databases including:
AWS DynamoDB
Snowflake (ODBC)
AWS RedShift
AWS DocumentDB
Azure CosmosDB
GCP Spanner
GCP BigQuery
GCP FireStore
GCP MemoryTable
AWS Elaticache
AWS Neptune
AWS QLDB
Is there any design pattern I can employ to deal with this problem? How about python packages that can connect to those databases. Are there any similar code on GitHub?
Or it's easier to first load the data to one database such as MongoDB and then migrate it to other databases.

Comment: I am currently trying to do the loading one database by one database. The hard part of this task that different databases have different ways to initialising tables, each of them have different datatypes as well. Its very tedious to map datatype of one database to the corresponding datatype supported by other databases.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use some ORM frameworks like [`SQLAlchemy`](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for Python in programming or some ETL tools like [`Kettle`](https://community.hitachivantara.com/s/article/data-integration-kettle) (it's based on JDBC) to do the data transfer from dataframes to multiple cloud databases.

However, I think there is not a single solution which can support these whole different databases, as the figures below.

Fig 1. SQLAlchemy supports these databases, the screenshot comes from SQLAlchemy [Dialects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/index.html) page

[image]

Fig 2. The classic ETL tool, Kettle, supports these databases, the screenshot comes from Kettle [Special database issues and experiences](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Special+database+issues+and+experiences) page

[image]

So a mixed solution is: 
1. Manually to write a Python script using SQLAlchemy 
2. Directly use Kettle with some necessary plugins which support other additional databases (such as [inquidia/PentahoSnowflakePlugin](https://github.com/inquidia/PentahoSnowflakePlugin) for AWS DynamoDB Snowflake), even try to integrate with Python via its [CPython Script Executor](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/CPython+Script+Executor).

Hope it helps.